# Select IE и css ширина элемента и выпадающего списка

Tags: html, css

Есть `<select>` у которого через стиль задана ширина(200px), во всех популярных браузерах кроме IE выпадающий список отображается по ширине самого длинного элемента а сам select на заданую ширину, в IE он отображается обрезаным до размера указаного в стиле,
возможно ли както для IE задать отдельную ширину для выпадающего списка и самого select`а?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [How to fix html drop down width problem in IE](http://dropdownwidthproblem.blogspot.com/2011/07/i-was-on-google-round-clock-for.html?spref=bl)
2. [Select dropdown with fixed width cutting off content in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie)
3. [Dropdownlist width in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960/dropdownlist-width-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению этот баг победить можно только хитростями, можно в момент наведения и выбора пунктов из списка изменять ширину селекта на auto, но мне такой вариант не нравиться, остается только стилизировать селект с помощью javascript или jquery. Тогда можно будет задавать любые размеры для выпадающего блока и самого псевдо-селекта используя цсс.